# Prompt for inserting label when using theorem style environments in latex

Tags: latex, auctex

When inserting the environment `equation` (by `C-c C-e equation`) in latex-mode, emacs shows a prompt to insert a label. It is desirable to have the same prompt for a theorem-style environment like `lem` defined in the document. When I do `C-c C-e lem`, the environment `lem` is correctly inserted, but a prompt for setting the label does not appear.

What is the procedure in order to have this prompt?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{lem}

\end{lem}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}

\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an up-to-date version of AUCTeX, say from ELPA, you have 2 choices:

1.) Set something like to this in your init file:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "latex"
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
    (lambda () (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist '("lem" . "lem:"))))
  (when (boundp 'reftex-label-alist)
    (add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist
                 '("lem" ?m "lem:" "~ref{%s}" nil ("Lemma" "lemma") nil))))
```

2.) Set the information on a per-file basis in the local variables of your .tex file:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% eval: (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist '("lem" . "lem:"))
%%% eval: (add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist '("lem" ?m "lem:" "~ref{%s}" nil ("Lemma" "lemma") nil))
%%% End:
```

You need the second `eval` only when you're using RefTeX.

Then open your .tex file, hit <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> so that AUCTeX parses your `lem` environment and you should be set.

Comment: I tested the first solution with auctex 11.89 and emacs 25.1, and after hit of `c-c c-n` and `c-c c-e lem` only a prompt for the `Heading` appears and the prompt for inserting label does not show up.

Comment: Unfortunately the second solution does not for me either.

Comment: @Name - For me, it works if I `eval ` (`C-x C-e`) the two `(add-to-list ...)` in a .tex file and hit `C-c C-n C-c C-e lem RET`.  What do you see if you hit `C-h v LaTeX-environment-list RET` and look for the `"lem"` entry?  Also check the values of `LaTeX-label-alist` and `reftex-label-alist` when in your .tex file.  Do you see the entries for `"lem"`?

Comment: Yes I see the entry for "lem" in `LaTeX-environment-list`.

Comment: @Name - I updated my answer: For 1), I had to use `LaTeX-mode-hook` for `LaTeX-label-alist`.  For 2), a `)` went lost while pasting the code for `reftex-label-alist`.  Please check again.  Both solutions work for me.